# How to know packet loss stats of specific TCP socket in Linux?

Tags: tcp

In other words, if I open a TCP socket the usual way, is there a way in Linux to retrieve packet loss counts for that particular socket from the process that created the socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TCP_INFO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html). This will give you a [`struct tcp_info`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h) that has among other members one called `tcpi_lost`:

```
...
164         __u32   tcpi_unacked;
165         __u32   tcpi_sacked;
166         __u32   tcpi_lost;
167         __u32   tcpi_retrans;
168         __u32   tcpi_facke
...
```

Although that member doesn't have documentation, one can see it relates to "lost packets" because it is set like this

```
info->tcpi_lost = tp->lost_out
```

And [`lost_out` does have a comment](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tcp.h):

```
u32     lost_out;       /* Lost packets                 */
```

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant. I had read all kinds of small letters in the man page, but never thought about checking the header. Thank you very much!!